# Audio Tag Not Working in Safari

Tags: html, audio, safari

I recently uploaded some radio I worked on to my site, and it plays fine in both Chrome and FireFox, however when I test it in Safari, it simply says “loading.”

This is the code I’m using:

```
        <source src=“x.ogg" type="audio/ogg">

        <source src=“x.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">

        Your current browser does support this audio.
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: which version of safari are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Safari do not support only Ogg file-format for this tag.

Please, check if you have `x.mp3` file in same directory, as your `.html` file.

Comment: Yes, I have both an x.mp3 and ogg file in the same directory as the html file

Comment: @climber which version of safari are you using? try to update it, anyway (http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6104)

Comment: currently on version 7.1.3

Comment: @climber try to remove `<source src=“x.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">` it might help

Comment: ended up saving another version as a wav file in addition to the other two and it works on safari now.